# Swift emulation of C array of specific size

Tags: arrays, swift, typedef, type-alias

I want to be able to create variables that are arrays of a specific size *and* pre-allocated.  In C this could be done like so:

```
typedef float vec16f[16];
vec4f myPresizedPreInitializedArray;
myPresizedPreInitializedArray[2]=200.0f
```

How would one do this in Swift?

I have tried the following:

- `typealias PositionVector = [Double]` has no size constraint nor pre-initialization
- `class Vector4D: Array<Any> {}` results in the error `Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Array<Any>'`

Comment: Why not simply a struct with x, y, z, w members?

Comment: @tuple_cat because eventually I want a type alias that represents a 4*4=16 element array

Comment: (Unrelated to the question, but note that your C example array is _not_ pre-initialized: it contains random values.)

Comment: Yes, @tuple_cat you are correct.  I meant that the space was pre-allocated.  Updating with your observation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is a struct with a static member as template

```
struct Template {
    static let vec4 = [Float](repeatElement(10.0, count: 4))
}

var newVec = Template.vec4
newVec[2] = 200.0
```

Due to value type semantics you get always a copy of `vec4`.

Comment: I like this solution, but let's say I wanted to `return newVec` from a function.  What would it's return type be?

Comment: It's simply `[Float]`.

Comment: anyway I can enforce types in a function declaration?  I think I have to do this 'func multiplyMatrixAndMatrix(a: [Float], b: [Float]) -> [Float] {`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a struct that wraps an array, and provides a `[]` operator:

```
struct Vec4<T> {
    private var array: [T]

    init(_ x: T, _ y: T, _ z: T, _ w: T) {
        array = [x, y, z, w]
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        get {
            return array[index]
        }
        set {
            array[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Or to make it more efficient:

```
struct Vec4<T> {
    private var x, y, z, w: T

    init(_ x: T, _ y: T, _ z: T, _ w: T) {
        (self.x, self.y, self.z, self.w) = (x, y, z, w)
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> T {
        get {
            switch index {
                case 0: return x
                case 1: return y
                case 2: return z
                case 3: return w
                default: preconditionFailure("invalid Vec4 subscript index")
            }
        }
        set {
            switch index {
                case 0: x = newValue
                case 1: y = newValue
                case 2: z = newValue
                case 3: w = newValue
                default: preconditionFailure("invalid Vec4 subscript index")
            }
        }
    }
}
```